# The email address used to help trust my PC, is no longer valid, how do I fix that?

Tags: windows-8, windows-8-upgrade

A few nights ago I upgraded my Windows 7 PC to Windows 8. This morning, when I logged into my PC, I noticed the little flag in the system tray, in desktop mode, had a red "X" on it.

I checked it and one of the issues was my needing to tell Windows 8 that I trusted my PC. I clicked on the link to trust my PC, and saw the button to tell it to trust my PC, and so I did.

After doing that it send it had sent out an email to a really old email address I had, which hasn't been valid for many years.

Now what? Will that "trusting my PC" be invalid, because I can't respond to it (which certainly isn't true, if it's sending messages to so old email address). I didn't even know that Windows still had such an old email address.

I'm concerned that I won't have a trust relationship with my own PC, that somehow or other whatever holds onto my information has old information and that I am not sure how to change it in as fast a manner as possible so that I can trust my own PC.

How do I do these things?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. Login to your [Microsoft Account](https://account.live.com/).
2. Click [**Edit security info**](https://account.live.com/Proofs/Manage) link in **Password and security info** section.
3. In **Alternate email address** section:

   1. Remove your old address.
   2. Add the current address.
   3. Add more email addresses if you like.

On this page [Your security info protects your account](https://account.live.com/Proofs/Manage) you can also manage the list of **Trusted PC** by removing some of the devices.

---

Also check the list of alternative email address in the **Notifications** section:

1. Click [**Notifications**](https://account.live.com/Notifications) on the right.
2. Click [**Manage email preferences**](https://account.live.com/ManageAssocIds).

Page titled **Your email addresses** will open.

You will see your *preferred email address* as well as the list of email addresses associated with this account.

Click **Change** link under your preferred email address.
Select new preferred address from the list or add a new one.

Click **Save** to apply changes.

If you changed to address, the system will send a confirmation mail to that address. Follow the instructions in that email to confirm it.

After that you can resend the confirmation message from Windows 8 computer to trust the PC.

---

On the *Your email addresses* page, you can:

- Remove your old address from the list of email address.
- Add another email address, if you like.

Comment: Thank you, I've gone to the page that you linked to, and I found it lists my Hotmail.com/Outlook.com email addresses. When I clicked on the link from the Action Center, it send me to a page titled, "Your security info protects your account", and I found it had a really old, defunked email address which I haven't used in many years. I changed it, but it won't go into effect until Dec. 16. Can this Trusting of my PC late until then, or will Windows 8 stop working at some point before then?

Comment: I've updated my answer. Why won't your new email address go into effect before Dec 16? I believe Windows won't stop working: it just can't sync some application settings unless you established trust with your PC.

Comment: I've no idea why it won't go into effect until Dec 16, but that's what the email from Microsoft said. I hope to learn more tomorrow, when people get back from the Thanksgiving holiday.